# JavaScript setTimeout not firing after Window.Open

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios5, ios4

I have an ASP.Net web page that currently works on the iOS4 but not on the iOS5.

On the parent web page I have a button that opens a child window. And I do a setTimeout refresh thing in the parent window right after the open window call.

I noticed on the iPhone iOS5 that when it opens the child window, the setTimeout function in the parent page is not called until I go back to the parent window and then back to the child window to see the update.

Here's a snippet of my code in the parent page and where I think is the problem

```
WindowManager.OpenWindow('...')
t = setTimeout(function() { handles[0].testfx(); }, 1000);
```

this runs on iOS4 but not on iOS5.

Any ideas?

Comment: With no details on HOW you refresh, I don't think anyone will be able to help.

Comment: Maybe the ISO5 is stop javascript execution when the page is on background to save batteries or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS5 does indeed pause JavaScript when a window is not the active window. There is nothing you can do about this, so the best you can do is try to alter your setup so that JavaScript does not need to be run when your window is in the background.

You said you are doing a `setTimeout refresh thing in the parent window`. WHY are you doing this? Frankly, it sounds a little bit odd -- why do you want to be refreshing anything when the user can't even see your page? What exactly does the line `handles[0].testfx();` do for you?

Comment: There may be many reasons to continue to process JS while the window is not active.  Off the top of my head, one might be to keep alive some type of connection to a server for a short period so the user doesn't always have to re-establish connections or credentials when they switch back to the page.

Comment: I think chrome is doing something similar, would be useful to investigate this.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a suggestion, since I don't have access to test this, but you may be able to hack around this using by using `window.postMessage`.  An example of this can be found [here](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts).

In your case, you would probably want to check if a required amount of time had elapsed, and if not, call `window.postMessage` again, otherwise, call your handler.

I'm not sure how quickly calls to `window.postMessage` will be processed, if at all, when not in the active window.